# Split multi-valued cells paired with other multi-valued cells in other rows

Tags: openrefine

I'm working on some data in openrefine where many cells have multiple values that pair to a single value each in another multi-value cell in a different row.  I want to turn that into one row with each paired data so turn something like this

| Name | Account Number |
| --- | --- |
| John; Jennifer; JT | 0239; 2191; 1788 |
| JT | 1788 |
| Janet; John | 0591; 0239 |

into this:

| Name | Account Number |
| --- | --- |
| John | 0239 |
| Jennifer | 2191 |
| JT | 1788 |
| JT | 1788 |
| Janet | 0591 |
| John | 0239 |

Is this possible to do? If so any suggestions on how to do so?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831582/split-multi-valued-cells-in-more-than-one-column-into-rows-open-refine) but it didn't get me there.

EDIT:
Here's what happens when I split each row using Edit Multi-Valued Cells and the semicolon separator. I'm unsure how to get the names next to the account numbers as [fill down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39318159/20246308) wouldn't work.

| Name | Account Number |
| --- | --- |
| John | 0239 |
|  | 2191 |
|  | 1788 |
| Jennifer |  |
| JT |  |
| JT | 1788 |
| Janet | 0591 |
|  | 0239 |
| John |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept you are searching for is cell splitting for multi-valued cells.
For details see the documentation about [cell editing](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/cellediting#split-multi-valued-cells).

If you do not have a [record structure](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/exploring#rows-vs-records) yet I suggest you apply the cell splitting command from right to left.

1. Split the cells in the column "Account Number" on the separator ";" via "Edit cells" => "Split multi-valued cells".
2. Split the cells in the column "Name" on the separator ";" via "Edit cells" => "Split multi-valued cells".
3. Remove leading and trailing white space in both columns via "Edit cells" => "Common transforms" => "Trim leading and trailing white space" (see documentation about [cell editing](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/cellediting#trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace) for details).

You can forgo step 3 by activating the regular expression checkbox in the cell splitting dialog and use a regular expression like "\s*;\s*" as separator.

Comment: Thanks. I found this but it only got me part way. I end up with the fields not lining up and no obvious way to delete the empty cells and move the filled cells up.

Comment: This happens when you split the cells going from left to right. Try splitting the cells starting with the rightmost column.